# How can I replace the numbers after the dot?

Tags: notepad++, regex, sublime-text-3, sublime-text

I have a json file in my hand, I want to replace the numbers here so that there are 2 digits after the dot. I am using (Sublime Text, Notepad). can you help me? for example; I want to write 32.48 instead of 32.4877372383

```
                    "calory": "32.4877372383",
                    "carbohydrt": "5.44751985283",
                    "protein": "1.75822099387",
                    "fat": "0.155740956864",
                    "calcium": "8.71466176412",
                    "cholestrl": "0.0",
                    "fiber_td": "1.85840511552",
                    "iron": "0.711263854542",
                    "lipid_tot": "0.155740956864",
                    "potassium": "87.793890567",
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Find what: `(\.\d{2})\d+`
- Replace with `$1`
- Search mode: Regular expression

[image]

Comment: this is really awesome! where should i start to learn regex rules and their meaning

Comment: You can google for books. There are good books out there that will help you started. On this website, check the answers from [Toto](https://superuser.com/users/763386/toto). He is excellent with regex and I have learned a lot from his answers.

Comment: @theoyuncu8: [A good place to test regex](https://regex101.com/)